# How to remove equal values ​in the list?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I need to create tabs for each element of the list that is not repeated. In the following code, I need to create a Tab with value 001 and another with value 002. But I end up creating 7 with value 001.

```
var listaNova : MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
    for (abastecimento in lista!!){
        listaNova.add(abastecimento.station.toString())
    }


    for(i in listaNova){
        select_bar.addTab(select_bar.newTab().setText(i))
    }
```

Comment: Use a set instead of a list. `val listaNova = lista!!.map { it.station.toString() }.toSet()`

Comment: @Tenfour04 why is your comment not an Answer?

Comment: @clvrmnky I don't usually answer either when (1) I think the question should likely be closed due to the site's rules but I don't currently have the time to explain why or find the question theirs is a duplicate of when I can just take five seconds to help them. (2) The question is from a new user that is not forthcoming with much detail, so I predict that if I do answer, I am likely to get many follow-up questions in the comments that are hard to answer succinctly/quickly, so I just don't want to deal with it.

Comment: @Tenfour04 while I understand this feeling, it means now we have yet another unanswered, abandoned Q&A. But the comment literally answered the question because you identified what was actually being answered. Follow-up questions are always a possibility, and here is where the prudent choice is, again, *not* to comment. Either vote to delete this Question if it doesn't meet site criteria, or let's  have a simple answer that may help another novice in the future.

Comment: @ldPr if this comment has helped you there is probably nothing wrong with waiting a bit and, if no one creates an Answer to this Question, "sniping" it yourself by self-answering.

Comment: In this case it was more along the first reason. Surely there is a question out there that this is a duplicate of because Sets are so fundamental. I didn't want to take the time to properly moderate this one. Since it's destined to either be closed as duplicate or orphaned with no answer, leaving a comment doesn't hurt anything. A proper answer should be more than a one-liner anyway. To help future readers it would need a more thorough explanation.

Comment: @clvrmnky I'm new here, if you prefer I can delete the question

Comment: @ldPr I think it's a reasonable question if it has not already been answered. Take the [tour] to see what SE sites are all about. If the Answer helped you and the community keeps this Q&A you can just self-answer and then future visitors will also be helped.

Answer (score 0):

Use a set instead of a list. val listaNova = lista!!.map { it.station.toString() }.toSet()